# AAC decoder for ARM Cortex A9

Tags: arm, aac, bare-metal

I trying to develop an application to decode AAC on an ARM Cortex A9 processor. I will not be using an OS. Therefore this will be a bare-metal application.
Are there any libraries already available for this?

I used mstorsjo-fdk-aac library on windows and Ubuntu. Is it possible to compile it for ARM to run on without an OS?

Can anyone point me in the correct direction? I searched a lot in the internet but could not get anywhere.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't run it without OS

Answer (score 1):

The fdk-aac codec library does depend on a `libc`, for standard C functions like `malloc`, `free`, math functions like `sin`, stdio for file handling etc. If you run on bare metal, you need to provide these functions somehow. (If you don't need the sublibrary for opening files, you probably don't need to provide the stdio functions, or it is ok to replace them with stubs.) Even if the files are C++, they don't seem to use the standard C++ library, so you probably don't need to provide that.

Luckily most of these functions seem to be separated out for easy replacement/redirection - have a look at `libSYS/src/genericStds.cpp` to see which facilities it depends on from the platform.